# Take pictures and save it to gallery instead of app files

Tags: java, android, file, camera

**What I want?**

I want the user to be able to take pictures (save it to gallery) , view them and then upload it to server.
The image size shouldn't be more than 1 MB.

**What I did?**

I'm able to take photo by creating a file first and then view them

**What is the issue?**

1. The image is saved in internal storage -> android -> data -> ..-> appname
   I don't think it's good idea to save file there ,
   I think it will affect the performance/size of my app -not sure-
2. The image size is 5-7 MB , I think it's because of the resolution 5664x4248
   What I want to do is after saving image to gallery , I will have the URI of it I will read it and resize its height and width and then upload it to server. Is is good idea?

Here's my code

Creating file

```
String currentPhotoPath;
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    //File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Start camera intent

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int requestCode) {
   try {

       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
               Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity() , new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA} , CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE_SHIPMENT_1);

       } else {
           Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
           if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
               // Create the File where the photo should go
               File photoFile = null;
               try {
                   photoFile = createImageFile();
               } catch (IOException ex) {
                   // Error occurred while creating the File
               }
               // Continue only if the File was successfully created
               if (photoFile != null) {
                   try {
                       Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                               "appname.fileprovider",
                               photoFile);
                       takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                       startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode);
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   } catch (Exception e ) {
   }
}
```

paths xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: `What I want to do is after saving image to gallery , I will have the URI of it I will read it and resize its height and width and then upload it to server. Is is good idea?` So after the camera app saved the picture to the storage location you indicated you can of course resize the picture before uploading. You dont need an uri as you have a File instance already pointing to your image file.

Answer (score 0):

getExternalFilesDirectory gives you that folder
And due to new storage restrictions since Q, you better stick to ehat you've done and provide those files using SAF
but for older versions you can use a more appropriate folder like photos inside external storage

Comment: Why do you think it's better? It won't affect the size of my app? Also all the other apps like whatsapp , instagram they save the photo directly to gallery rather than this folder

Comment: Like it or not, we won't be able to target less than sdk 30 within 6 months and "better" wasn't supposed to show what I like, it's better because it obeys what we're forced to. As Metallica said, Come crawling faster, obey your master

Comment: `they save the photo directly to gallery rather than this folder` One cannot save fotos to the gallery to begin with. As 'the gallery' is no storage location but just an app that can show images on your device.

Comment: `It won't affect the size of my app?` You cannot change the size of your app at runtime. Its determined at compile time and install time. Further you cannot store photos in your app at runtime. You would store them in a storage location of your device.

Comment: `provide those files using SAF` On Android 11 SAF has no access to private directories in Android folder.

Comment: @blackapps Okay but can you explain to me the case , I checked whataspp folder in  internal storage -> android -> data -> ..->whatsapp. But it's not including any photos , rather they are saved only in gallery. And what about the performance , imagine user is taking 50 image per day , the size of this folder will become very large thus i think it will effect the performance isn't?

Comment: `whataspp folder in internal storage -> android -> data -> ..->whatsapp. ` As you are a programmer you should tell full paths in normal notation. That would be: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<whatsappid>. But pictures there would not be shown by gallery apps. I rather think you mean folder /storage/emulated/0/Whatsapp.

Comment: If you think it will effect permormance then is there an alternative? Which?

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for your feedback but I'm in the learning process :) we are not born knowing and understanding everything.